# Using two conditional css if statements uses neither style sheet

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

At my wit's end here. Trying to implement two different style sheets, one for IE and one for when it's not IE. In every example I've ever seen this is exactly the way you're supposed to do this. Can anyone spot any mistakes in this? Seems like it should be simple enough.

```
<!--[if !IE]><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/login/css/correctlogin.css'/><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/login/css/ielogin.css'/><![endif]-->
```

Comment: How is it erring? Do both stylesheets display for IE only? Do neither display for IE? Do all browsers display both stylesheets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the `!IE` conditional comment, the correct format is `<!--[IF !IE]>--> ... <!-- <![endif]-->`, because non-IE browsers do not have a special treatment for the conditional comments.

```
<!--[if !IE]> --><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/login/css/correctlogin.css'/><!-- <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/login/css/ielogin.css'/><![endif]-->
```

See also: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html
PS. Conditional comments are not supported in IE10 any more.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about IE10, I was not aware of that (I haven't looked into IE10 much yet).

Answer (score 2):

The if not IE statement is redundant. All you need is an if IE statement.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/login/css/correctlogin.css'/>
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/login/css/ielogin.css'/>
<![endif]-->
```

This tells every browser to use `correctlogin.css` and if the browser is IE, THEN also use `ielogin.css`

Comment: This is possibly a better solution, as most of the code across the two stylesheets should match. The `ielogin.css` should then only have IE specific corrections.

Comment: This is slightly off-topic but one of my corrections is the _removal_ of background-image. In that case I actually need to not use the original style-sheet property.

Comment: @buddyp450... Why? Simply set `background-image: none;` in the IE stylesheet.