# HTML CSS IE7 Condional Codes

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have these HTML conditional codes for IE 7 yet they don't appear to be working.

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/stylesie.css" />
<![endif]-->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css" />
```

is there something wrong with them or something I am missing?

Comment: This ought to work. Can you provide a demo? If you want to ignore `styles.css` for IE, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709715/using-two-conditional-css-if-statements-uses-neither-style-sheet).

Answer (score 4):

If you adjust your rules for IE7 in stylesie.css, then it should be loaded *after* your original css file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css" />

<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/stylesie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Rules for a selector with the same [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity) will overwrite old ones, so IE7 will parse stylesie.css first and overwrite those rules with the ones from styles.css.

[Basic example of this behavior:](http://jsfiddle.net/YYpUj/)

```
div, div.red{
    color:red;
}
div{
    color:blue;
}
```

This will result in a blue color in all `<div>`, except the one tagged with the class `red`.

Answer (score 0):

From the given information I can only try to guess: for me it looks that `"/css/styles.css"` overwrites some CSS properties of `"/css/stylesie.css"` since included after. So I'd try to include it before:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css" />

<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/stylesie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the position you inserted it is the issue. Your page first loads IE-definitions, then adds your CSS supposed to be the "default" one for all browsers. Now if there are definitions for the same elements like in your IE-Version, that will simply override those.